# d3.js bar chart sorting: can't figure out how to sort x-axis labels along with bars

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm making a sortable d3 bar chart based on [Scott Murray's tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html#_click_to_sort), but he doesn't explain how to sort the x-axis labels along with the bars, and I haven't been able to figure it out despite various attempts. Here's my code; the relevant function is "sortBars" near the bottom, but I've included the rest for context.

([Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jslutzky/f6bqsk6g/), but I can't seem to translate the data correctly from my JSON.)

The bar heights are data.days (which are numbers, i.e. number of days); the labels are data.names. How do I sort the labels?

```
  function retirements(presidents){
    var data = presidents;

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 180, left: 80},
        width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(data.names)
        .rangeBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, Math.ceil(d3.max(data.days)/1000)*1000])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return d + " days";
      })

    var svg = d3.select(".container")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    var barWidth = width / data.days.length;

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data.days)
      .enter().append("rect")
      // this might be affected:
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d) + 1; })
        .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.9em")
          .attr("dy", ".25em")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-50)" );

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "-6em")
        .attr("dx","-15em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Days");

    var sortOrder = false;

    var sortBars = function() {
      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .sort(function(a, b) {
          if (sortOrder) {
            return d3.descending(a, b);
          } else {
            return d3;
          }
         })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; })

    $("#descending").on("click", function(){
     sortOrder = true;
     sortBars();
    });

    $("#chronological").on("click", function(){
      sortOrder = false;
      sortBars();
     });
    };
```

Comment: Would you mind making a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Would be easier to visualize what exactly you are trying to sort -- the guide shows how to sort the bars so he sorts the values but it seems like you want to be able to sort the labels on the x-axis?

Comment: Is'nt this the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520950/animated-sort-stacked-bar-chart-d3-js click on the sort check box in the fiddle to see teh sorting work

Comment: @aug - Yes, I'm trying to sort the labels on the X-axis. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jslutzky/f6bqsk6g/), but my data originally comes from JSON and I can't seem to copy it correctly into the JS file directly.

Comment: @Cyril - I've posted a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jslutzky/f6bqsk6g/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all rather than having 2 different arrays of presidents and its data.
Lets make it into single object so tat sorting is easy.

```
var newData = [];
data.names.forEach(function(d, i) {
  newData.push({
    name: d,//now object will have a name
    days: data.days[i],//days will hold the president data
    id: i //id of the record for chronology sorting
  })
});
```

Now for sorting do this:

```
var sortBars = function() {

    if (sortOrder){
    //sort on basis of date
    var sorted = newData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.descending(a.days, b.days);
    });
  } else {
    //sort on basis of id
    var sorted = newData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(a.id, b.id);
    });
  }
  //set the domain post sorting  
  x.domain(sorted.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  //sort the bars
  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      if (sortOrder) {
        return d3.descending(a.days, b.days);
      } else {
        return d3.ascending(a.id, b.id);
      }
    });
  //make transition
  var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
    delay = function(d, i) {
      return i * 50;
    };

  //transition dor xa axis labels
  transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.9em")
    .attr("dy", ".25em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-50)")
    .delay(delay);
  //transition for bars.
  transition.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)";
    });
}
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/foxv4aku/4/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect. I had actually realized I needed to change my data into a single object, so I'd changed my Ruby method to fix the data, but I wasn't sure about the rest. Much appreciated.